# javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort() continuously invoked leads to OOM in PermGen

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, out-of-memory, permgen

Improving java application, we are now facing migration from Axis to Jax-WS.

Currently we encounter the following problem: in our generated service class, inherited from `javax.xml.ws.Service` there is a call to `Service#getPort`

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "SomeServiceSoap")
public SomeServiceSoap getSomeServiceSoap() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://something", "SomeServiceSoap"), SomeServiceSoap.class);
}
```

and this method is called each time when we want to execute method on this service. However, in tests it leads to OOM in permgen.

Should I avoid calling it more than once - by creating cache/pool or other storage for returned objects? Or am I missing some other important feature of this implementation.

Comment: I doubt that calling method continuously can lead to Perm Gen OOM issue. It may be a code issue at server side code.

Comment: Permgen space stops grow as soon as I stop calling this exactly method reusing object it returns instead. And there is httpd with single sample file used as a server for tests.

Comment: If it would been a heap OOM issue, it may be associated with object creation and GC. But in case of Perm gen, it means the class is getting loaded everytime a call is made!! It is only possible, if the service is actually **loosing** the class reference after each call. Now the reasons could be many.. may be a bug into the 3rd party library, or may be a custom classloader in application is being used to load application classes, and a new classloader instance is created on every request (leaving the old one still live and holding class reference). Try using a different JAX-WS implementation.

Comment: I tried to dump permgen on error - here are tons of classes with name "DelegatingLoader" from internals of com.sun...ws :( It is really not proxies temselves are doing this mess.

Answer (score 1):

Though I did not found how exactly jax-ws implementation do this nasty trick, I've discovered instead that to avoid problem I need to change jaxws-rt from version `2.2.6` (which was used in our pom-files, but is almost two year old) to `2.2.8`.

This library version change completely fixes the issue. I've tested it both in Java 6 and Java 7.